# Regular expression for currency field

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

Please can someone help me to write a JavaScript regular expression? I need to write a field that will allow examples of the following:

£1, £1.00, 1p

I do not want it to allow £ and p together. I also don't want it to allow more than 1 decimal. So far, I have the following:

```
/^(\u00A3)?([0-9\.]+)p?$/
```

This doesn't work 100% accurately though. Any help or guidance would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might try this regex:

```
^(?:\u00A3([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)|[0-9]+p)$
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/uR6kH7)

This will allow up to 2dp for pounds. If you want to allow more, just use `+` instead:

```
^(?:\u00A3([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|[0-9]+p)$
```

Also, I didn't put decimals for pence. If you want to allow those too, you can use:

```
^(?:\u00A3([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?p)$
```

Comment: That's amazing help - thank you! and a great site. I'll definitely use that

Comment: @30secondstosam You're welcome! Should you want anything else related to your question, I'll be glad to assist :)

Comment: One more thing @Jerry - how do i allow for the £ symbol to be optional? is it by adding a question mark after u00A3 ? Thanks

Comment: Oh, yup, you do it just like you did in your question, put parens and a question mark `(\u00A3)?` and `(?:\u00A3)?` to improve speed a little bit (without the `?:` the parens become a capture group, meaning that the script will save what is inside and consume a little more memory).

Comment: Hi Jerry - sorry to bother again - getting errors using this with JavaScript on the link. that's where i need the expression to work. in JS

Comment: @30secondstosam It's just that the site I linked doesn't get the unicode characters xD Here's a demo with javascript code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6vAKD/).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/^(\u00A3[0-9\.]+)|([0-9\.]+p)$/
```